# Can search engines index pages generated by server side code?

Tags: scripting, search-engine, server-side

I'm guessing a site like stack overflow doesn't keep an html file around for every question ever asked. Instead, server-side code creates the page every time a question is clicked on(I think). Is it possible for search engines to index every quesiton on Stack Overflow, or would a page-per-question need to be kept in the directory so the search engine can crawl it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested by the [Dynamic URLs vs. static URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/09/dynamic-urls-vs-static-urls.html) post on the Official Google Webmaster Central Blog.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Search engines can index dynamically generated pages no problem. In fact, from the search engine bot's perspective, it can't really even distinguish between a dynamically generated page and a static one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's perfectly possible - when a link is followed the server returns HTML just like any other web page. The only difference is that the server generated it, rather than a person.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the client (be it a browser or search engine) is concerned, there is *no* difference between a server-generated page and a static file. They're virtually indistinguishable (depending on how the page is generated, it might be missing `Last-Modified` headers, etc). As such, yes, search engines can index generated pages without a problem.

That said, there is something to be said for giving them a hint. Using [sitemaps](http://www.sitemaps.org/), for example, gives a search engine a nice listing of all your pages, so it's less likely to miss them. More importantly, it can summarize last modified times, to focus the search engine's attention on what has changed recently. This isn't mandatory, but it does help - regardless of whether the pages are static HTML or generated.

Answer (score 0):

Any link that uses a GET can be followed by most crawlers.  Anything that requires a POST will generally be ignored.

The mechanism for generating the page is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

yes if this is not restricted by robot.txt or meta tags.Search engine requests web page like normal user,no one have access to server side code(if your site isn't hacked))

Answer (score 0):

Search engines can see pretty much anything on a given Web page that isn't hidden behind client-side code (i.e., JavaScript).

So, if there's a URL that you can enter into your browser's address bar to get this page, and this page is linked to from somewhere, a search engine will find it and "see" the same content that you do. The fact that the page was generated dynamically by a server is irrelevant to a search engine, since what is sent to a browser upon requesting a URL is still just an HTML file.

In other words, that HTML file doesn't exist in the same form on the server - i.e., it's actually some server-side code that generates HTML, not a static HTML file - but that's not what a search engine is crawling though and indexing, rather links to document URLs that are exactly what you see in your browser's address bar.